# sonarqube plugin development: widget can't access metrics

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sonarqube

I am trying to develop a custom SonarQube (4.3) plugin that has Decorator part and a widget that should display some sort of project metrics digest, i.e. code quality decision tree. I need it to access the metrics that are already collected by other plugins and stored in database.

I started with my widget just having plain text and something like this:

'Today is <%= Time.now.strftime('%A') %>'
got it on the dashboard, no problem.

as soon as I access one of the sonar ruby functions, for example:
'Number of lines <%= measure('lines').value %>'

it  throws an error in the browser:
*An error occurred while trying to display the widget "myWidget". Please contact the administrator.*

and respectively, in sonarqube server log I get this:

*2015.08.11 11:58:56 ERROR rails  Can not render widget myWidget: undefined method `measure' for nil:NilClass*

no matter which built in sonar ruby function I try, it seems to have no reference of it.

I have to confess that I don't understand how ruby's objects declared in *.rb files are linked to ruby's templates that reference those objects? None of the examples that I could find for Sonar plugin development can explain how it works? any help is greatly appreciated!!

cheers
victor

Comment: I am getting the same problem. Could you fix that, then how?

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at our [sample plugin](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-examples/blob/master/plugins/sonar-reference-plugin/) to see what you can do.

More precisely, you can check the [example_widget.html.erb file](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-examples/blob/master/plugins/sonar-reference-plugin/src/main/resources/example/example_widget.html.erb). You will see some code like:

`<%= format_measure('random') -%>`.

Comment: Thanks Fabrice! Yes , <%= format_measure('random') -%> doesn't cause a problem. Yet when I use something like  <%= trend_icon(measure('random')) %> I got the same complain I reported before: undefined method `measure' for nil:NilClass. I looked at the sample widget, you referred to. I understand parameters part of it, but still struggle with how the scope of ruby objects/methods (e.g. 'measure')  is defined in ruby template?

Comment: Hello Fabrice,I just build and deployed your sample plugin, and I have exact same problem with it, which I observed with my own plugin. Here is a top of error stack: 2015.08.14 10:36:16 ERROR [rails]  Can not render widget sample: undefined method `measure' for nil:NilClass
2015.08.14 10:36:16 ERROR [rails]   .C:/Sonar/sonarqube-4.3/web/WEB-INF/app/helpers/dashboard_helper.rb:42:in `measure'
2015.08.14 10:36:16 ERROR [rails]    compiled-template:6:in `_run_inline_1251540527. Is there anything, that you can think of, that I can try to make it work? Really appreciate your help!! cheers, victor

Comment: I am getting same problem. Can anyone help me?